# javascript to replace any number greater than 3 with 3

Tags: javascript

I have a replace filter that is looking for any occurrence of 4 and replacing it with 3. However, I want it to be dynamic, so instead of hard coding it to 4, I want the javascript to just look for any value greater than 3 and replace it with 3.

This is the code i have so far

```
res = scriptletInput.replace(/<3/i, "3");
scriptletResponse = "Success"; 
scriptletResult = res;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var scriptletInput= 'this is 1234567890 number';

var result = scriptletInput.replace(/[3-9]/g,'3');
scriptletResponse = "Success"; 
scriptletResult = result;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, this code is part working. in the sense that its replacing every number that more than 3 as required with 3 but its also changing the number of the items i want to count so e.g. its servers its counting and 1 of the names include: derf400146 so its changing these to def300133 how can i stop this from occurring? The number i want to change is place before server like 4 server: derf400146